# Unit of width/height properties of an SVG

Tags: css, svg

Given this code of svg, a blue rectangle is being drawn.

```html
<svg>
  <rect width="50" height="200" style="fill:blue"/>
</svg>
```

The blue rectangle size varies depending on the view port.
I assume that the unit `50` for the `width` property, is not just plain pixels. Otherwise it would have been the same across different screens.

So what is exactly the meaning of this unit?

Comment: In the above code, it looks it is the width and height in pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unit of measurement is `pixels`. You are not getting the correct result due to the behaviour of vector drawing in the svg element.

---

If you specify a height and width on your svg you will find the rectangle behaves as expected.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <rect width="50" height="200" style="fill:blue"/>
</svg>
```

The svg size should be the maximum extent of all content contained within it.
If only a rectangle resides inside it then you can make the containing svg the size you desire and simply use height / width 100% on your rectangle.

```html
<svg width="50" height="200">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:blue"/>
</svg>
```